# Networking not initialized with cloud-init on some Centos 7 images

Tags: centos, centos7, cloud-init

I'm trying to create KVM VMs of Centos 7 with cloud-init. I am using the images found at https://cloud.centos.org/centos/7/images/ .

In the `meta-data` file I put the following content:

```yaml
network-interfaces: |
  iface eth0 inet static
  address 10.0.0.10
  network 10.0.0.0
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  broadcast 10.0.0.255
  gateway 10.0.0.1
bootcmd:
 - ifdown eth0
 - ifup eth0
```

However I don't get the same behaviour depending on the image used (I tried a few):

- Centos-7, Centos-7-2009: The VM doesn't use the static IP given (the link is down)
- Centos-7-1805: The VM uses the static IP *but* SSH connection initialisation is very slow (a minute or two)
- Centos-7-1607: The VM uses the static IP, SSH works correctly, but the Ansible playbook I tried with an ordinary Centos-7 image (installed from an `iso` file) doesn't work perfectly on this image (issue with some packages missing), I would like to not change my playbook.

Is there a reason there are so much differences between the different images ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Thank you